# How to navigate back in angular2 apps?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building a single page application with multiple views served by a router.

Most of the info I have read says to inject `location:Location` as a service, then use `(click)='location.back'` to go back a view.

This doesn't work for me as if you start on a certain view and click back, you end up exiting the app and going to the previous website. I also get frequent page reloads when using this as a navigation method. Is there a history API, or some other way to handle navigation in an ng2 application?

Comment: Sounds like normal behavior. Where do you expect the browser to go when there's no page to navigate back to? Instead of using a "back" link in your UI, which is not very explicit, can you replace it with a link that takes the user to a screen that can act as the "parent screen"? For instance, if the user is viewing a specific item, the link could take them to the items list; if they're deep down a menu branch, the link could take them to the parent menu item, etc.

Comment: I could do that, but is there any way to detect whether or not the back link will go to a different host or hostname? I don't always want the navigation to go back to the dashboard, sometimes they will jump from another page.

Comment: I understand. The [CanDeactivate] (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanDeactivate-interface.html) lets you run some code **before** leaving a route, but I'm afraid it only works when navigating from an Angular route to another, not from a route to an external URL.

Comment: I would do it in plain JS. You can listen to URL changes with [window.onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) or [window.onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) and react accordingly.

Comment: @AngularFrance I think you're probably right, I'll write a service to do it without angular.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use location from angular common
like:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
    constructor(private _location: Location){ }
    goback(){
        this._location.back();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing, and what I've written in the question... I am looking for a way that won't exit the application by accident. You don't need to bind a goBack method here either, you can directly access the location service in the template.

Comment: yes, use in html like: 

`<a (click) = "_location.back()">Back</a>` 

but make `public _location:Location`

Answer (score 1):

Use This:

```
window.history.back();
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. Technically this works... even if it isn't the preferred method.

Comment: This is exactly what the back() method of the Location service in @angular/common does behind the scenes in the usual case of when you're using the @angular/platform-browser module. The advantage of the Angular method is that it is more general and works on other platforms supported by Angular as well.

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful

```
history: string[] = [];

constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .subscribe(event => {
            this.history.push(event.url);
        });
}

onBack() {
    if (this.history.length > 1) {
        // pop current page
        this.history.pop();
        // pop previous page (later it will be added)
        this.history.pop();
        window.history.back();
    }
}

onHome() {
    window.location.replace(window.location.origin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On ionic 4 this worked for me:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

...
constructor(private location: Location) {}

back() {
  this.location.back();
}
...
```